# Using a native android shared library for another application

Tags: android

I have an application that has a naive library in it. I want to have another application access the same so library.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an intent filter to an activity of the first application. Then you can send an activity to this application with the specific intent in order to get your job done and get the result.

Of course, you can add this library to your second application, but I suppose based on your question that this is not what you want. So, basically I think the first solution will do your job.

Hope this helps!